# How would I use grep on a single word in UNIX?

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I want to run a script in unix that will look for a specific pattern  inside a passed argument. The argument is a single word, in all cases. I cannot use grep, as grep only works on searching through files. Is there a better unix command out there that can help me?

Answer (score 5):

Grep can search though files, or it can work on stdin:

```
$ echo "this is a test" | grep is
this is a test
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're doing you may prefer to use bash pattern matching:

```
# Look for text in $word
if [[ $word == *text* ]]
then
  echo "Match";
fi
```

or regular expressions:

```
# Check is $regex matches $word
if [[ $word =~ $regex ]]
then
  echo "Match";
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `case/esac` as well. No need to call any external commands (for your case)

```
case "$argument" in
  *text* ) echo "found";;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

As of bash 3.0 it has a built in regexp operator =~

Checkout http://aplawrence.com/Linux/bash-regex.html

Answer (score 0):

```
if echo $argument | grep -q pattern
then
    echo "Matched"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

my File is:

```
$ cat > log 
loga

hai how are you loga

hai

hello

loga
```

My command is:

```
sed -n '/loga/p' log
```

My answer is:

```
loga

hai how are you loga

loga
```